# Why am I getting a positional indexer out of bounds error with Scikit-learn's RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, index-error

If this question is better put in CrossValidated, let me know. Thought I'd start here, since it's primarily a question about a specific error, which happens to be in a machine learning algorithm, rather than a question about approaches or methods.

I'm working on a machine learning project to forecast the number of deaths by US county from COVID on Kaggle. To tune the hyperparameters of the random forest regressor, I'm using sklearn's [RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV) class, but fitting it throws a `IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds`, though the traceback only references the pandas module. This does not happen when normally fitting the random forest regressor without the RandomizedSearchCV and using a simpler splitting method (no cross validation).

At first I thought it might be to do with the range of values that I passed to it, but I reduced the values for each parameter and all parameters, but get the same problem.

My current suspicion is that it's in the custom cross validation class that I'm using to do a split on multiple time series (`MultipleTimeSeriesSplit` in the code), but it seems to work on the training data just fine. It doesn't work on the labels alone, since the splitting depends on the `fips_target` column in the features. Im not confident that this is the current issue either, since attempting to split the labels results in a missing column error, not a positional index error.

What is causing this `IndexError`? How can I get it functioning?

The following code is for [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/), but if you're not on it, you should be able to download the necessary data set [here](https://www.kaggle.com/fireballbyedimyrnmom/us-counties-covid-19-dataset).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



import os
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))



covid = pd.read_csv("../input/us-counties-covid-19-dataset/us-counties.csv").dropna()

    
# label encoding
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

cat_features = ['fips']
encoder = LabelEncoder()

# Apply the label encoder to each column
encoded = covid[cat_features].apply(encoder.fit_transform)
covid = covid.assign(fips = encoded)


# target encoding
import category_encoders as ce
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

def train_valid_test_incremental(df, train_frac=0.75):
    
    train = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    test = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    
    for location in pd.unique(df.fips):
        idx = df.fips == location
        d = df.loc[idx]
        train = train.append(d.iloc[:int(train_frac*len(d.index))])
        test = test.append(d.iloc[int(train_frac*len(d.index)):])

    train = train.infer_objects()
    test = test.infer_objects()
    return train, test

print("splitting (non cv)")
train, test = train_valid_test_incremental(covid)

# Create the encoder itself
target_enc = ce.TargetEncoder()

# Fit the encoder using the categorical features and target
target_enc.fit(train[cat_features], train['deaths'])

# Transform the features, rename the columns with _target suffix, and join to dataframe
train = train.join(target_enc.transform(train[cat_features]).add_suffix('_target'))
test = test.join(target_enc.transform(test[cat_features]).add_suffix('_target'))

# split data and labels for test and train, keep useful features
feat_cols = train.drop(columns = ['county', 'state', 'fips', 'date', 'cases', 'deaths']).columns

feats_train = train[feat_cols]
feats_test = test[feat_cols]

deaths_train = train.deaths
deaths_test = test.deaths


# use forward chaining cv for each county "fips"
class MultipleTimeSeriesSplit():
    def __init__(self, n_cvs=5):
        self.n_cvs = n_cvs
        self.n_splits = self.n_cvs + 1
    
    def get_n_splits(self, X, y, groups):
        return self.n_splits
    
    def split(self, X, y=None, groups=None): # yielding no test data, same training data
        fips_groups = {fips: list(X[X.fips_target == fips].index) for fips in pd.unique(X.fips_target)}

        start = 0
        for n in range(2, self.n_cvs + 2):
            train, test = [], []
            for fips in pd.unique(X.fips_target):
                indices = fips_groups[fips]
                k_fold_size = len(indices) /  self.n_splits

                mid = int(k_fold_size*(n-1))
                stop = int(k_fold_size*n)

                train += indices[:mid]
                test += indices[mid: stop]
                            
            yield train, test
    
# create model, tune hyperparameters, and fit to data
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV, ParameterGrid, ParameterSampler
# Random search cv, need to use time series cv method

mtscv = MultipleTimeSeriesSplit()
rforest_deaths = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0)
rf_param_dist = ParameterGrid({'bootstrap': [True, False],
    'max_depth': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, None],
    'max_features': ['auto', 'sqrt'],
    'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 4],
    'min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10],
    'n_estimators': [10, 50, 100, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000]})
rf_rscv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=rforest_deaths, param_distributions = rf_param_dist, random_state=0, cv=mtscv, return_train_score=True)
rf_rscv.fit(feats_train, deaths_train)

training_pred_rf = rf_rscv.predict(feats_train)
train_rf_loss = mean_squared_error(deaths_train, training_pred_rf)

predictions_rf = rf_rscv.predict(feats_test)
test_rf_loss = mean_squared_error(deaths_test, predictions_rf)

print(f"Random Forest\ntraining error: {np.sqrt(train_rf_loss)}\t\ttesting error: {np.sqrt(test_rf_loss)}")
```

This minimal example does not include the functional fitting of the random forest regressor without cross validation, nor the other models that I'm testing out, nor the demographic data that I joined to the covid data.

---

The existing answer does not address my error. I'm really not sure how to diagnose or make progress on this myself

Comment: the link for the kaggle notebook is not working

Comment: Please post your minimal example here, **not** in some external link.

Comment: I had thought I'd tested it, sorry. Added the code here. Since I'm working in kaggle, I figure that would be the easier place for others to examine the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your function train_valid_test_incremental() is returning **None** . 
Run `print(len(train))` code below function code. 
`train, test = train_valid_test_incremental(covid)`.

Hence you are getting this error. Also for timeseries problems, please use LSTM/ARIMA models instead of RF.

Comment: That is not the result that I get. I get a length of 179111, even after double checking the minimal example code provided.

Comment: some timeout issues was there in Kaggle, found the real issue.
problematic code -> **(train.join(target_enc.transform(train[cat_features])**

I have shared the kernel with you on kaggle you can see it there too. 

You can add suffix using df.join as well. Please refer the guide below. The error is a syntax error.



dataframe join guide link -> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

dataframe  add suffix link -> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html

Comment: please put your answer here, both for easier reference, and so that others might benefit from the solution